# JavaScript text nodes properties

Tags: javascript, html, textnode, nodevalue

I'm little confused about properties of text nodes in JavaScript.
Let say that I have this piece of html:

```
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
    <title>JavaScript test</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="test.js"></script>
</head>
<body onload="load()">
    <div>
        <p>Paragraph 1</p>
        <p>Paragraph 2</p>
    </div>
    <ul>
        <li>1.</li>
        <li>2.</li>
    </ul>
</body>
```

And `onload()` function:

```
function load()
{
    var bodyChildren = document.childNodes[0].childNodes;
    for(var i = 0; i < bodyChildren.length; i++) 
    {
        alert(bodyChildren[i].nodeType
            + ": " + bodyChildren[i].nodeName
            + ": " + bodyChildren[i].nodeValue);
    }
}
```

This http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_navigation.asp tells:
*"nodeValue for text nodes is the text itself"*, but I'm getting this output:

```
3: #text: 
1: DIV: null
3: #text: 
1: UL: null
3: #text:
```

Can you explain me why `nodeValue` returns `null` for `element node` and "nothing" for `text node`?

**Edit:**
The stuff about white spaces is nicely described here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Whitespace_in_the_DOM

Comment: I wonder how `document.childNodes[0]` gets you the body element?

Comment: It's `HTML node`, and it's children are `head` and `body`.

Comment: Really, I had to change it to `document.body.childNodes` to get it working, but if it works for you it's probably fine ?

Comment: Yes it also works for me. But I'm not having problem with children of body, but with text content of children nodes. I'll go through your and other answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> why nodeValue returns `null` for element node

Because [element nodes](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#Node-ELEMENT_NODE) don't have values. They basically only have a name, attributes and children.

> …and "nothing" for text node?

It does return you something: the whitespace between those element nodes.

Comment: Oh I got it now, I need to get `nodeValue` of element node's child, not of element node itself which returns the piece of the text before element's `<..>` brackets. In this case, piece of the text is the whitespace. Thanks for my better understanding of DOM!

Answer (score 3):

That's what `nodeValue` does according to the [specification](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nodeValue), it returns this

```
Comment               - content of the comment
Document              - null
DocumentFragment      - null
DocumentType          - null
Element               - null
NamedNodeMap          - null
EntityReference       - null
Notation              - null
ProcessingInstruction - entire content excluding the target
Text                  - content of the text node
```

Note that it returns `null` for anything **but** comments, textNodes and processing instruction, for all other node types `null` is explicitly returned.

To get the text content of an Element node, use `textContent` (`innerText` for older IE), to get the HTML of an Element node, use `innerHTML`

Comment: Also thanks for this exact answer. The accepted answer kicked me to understanding of element vs. text node.